# Tutorials and Introductions to C++ Expression Templates

Tags: c++, templates, arrays, metaprogramming, expression-templates

What are good introductions to the creation of C++ expression template systems? I would like to express arithmetic on user defined types while avoiding temporary values (which may be large), and to learn how to do this directly rather than applying an existing library.

I have found [Todd Veldhuizen's original paper](http://eprints.kfupm.edu.sa/40035/1/40035.pdf) and an example from the [Josuttis C++ Templates book](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/exprtmpl/exprmain.cpp.html), and an article by [Kreft & Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/ExpressionTemplates/ExpressionTemplates.htm). It is mentioned in Lecture 6 of a course on [Modern C++](http://www.cs.aau.dk/~nesotto/modern_cpp/2008.html), referring back to Josuttis.The POOMA library [background](http://www.nongnu.org/freepooma/tutorial/background.html) introduces expression templates nicely.

I am looking for *simple*, clear expositions.

Comment: Boost lambda library seems to use this technique. From my experience it is very cumbersome to use and still has lots of limitations; I wouldn't be surprised if there were no simple explanations of how this works too.

Comment: boost::lambda has a different purpose than expression templates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get a copy of *[C++ Templates:  The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842)*.

The code example to which you link doesn't have the accompanying text, which is quite helpful (the chapter on expression templates is 22 pages long).  Without the text, all you have is code without any comments or explanation as to what it does and how and why it does it.

Comment: Vandevoorde and Josuttis have the only really complete description.  The topic is never going to be *simple*, because it's a topic that's both complicated and difficult, but they do the best job.

Answer (score 7):

I found [Expression Templates Demystified](http://shoddykid.blogspot.com/2008/07/expression-templates-demystified.html) to be fairly well explained. It starts off by showing how to implement mathematical expressions without templates and shows the basic building blocks and concepts.

The second part of the article shows how to refactor the initial implementation to use templates instead for improved performance and reduced code.

IMO, the article is a good alternative to the expression template chapter in 'C++ Templates: The Complete Guide'.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly encourage to look up Eric Niebler Boost.Proto library.
A very fine introduction materials can be found over C++-next :

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/08/expressive-c-introduction/

and his talk at boost'con 2010 is also very interesting

Answer (score 0):

You've got all the sources except for the scientific c++ book, which is really just the original paper (wrt to this topic anyway) and is pretty out dated.  You could look at C++ Template Metaprogramming for more modern techniques built from the expression templates ideas, but something "simple" is not going to be readily available until it IS simple.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing the Boost Operators at [Boost Operators - Arithmetic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#arithmetic).  These are templated methods that extend fundamental arithmetic and comparison operations.

Answer (score 0):

for what you want to do, you should look at the code of **Boost.ublas** as it does exactly that.

Start with the file `vector.hpp` and then go back into the hierarchy (parents of `vector<>`). Matrices are a bit more complex but the mechanisn is the same.

Now I may advise not to try to reproduce the complexity of the library as a first try, like `ublas_expression` and things like that. You can do it simpler by making your type the base object and then implement a binary operator.

Look here too: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-expression-minimal.html