# Copying big objects, c++

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, copying

I am sure this has been answered, but I am no programmer and couldn't find/understand the appropriate answer.
Suppose I have a massive class `big` for which would like to overload a binary operator, say `operator +`.

1. Is there a sane way to make `big X=Y+Z` to build the sum directly into `X`, instead of 
   creating temporary object, copying it to `X` and then destroying the temporary?
2. The only thing that come into my mind is to wrap `big` into another class `small` that will contain the pointer to `big` and add `int use;` number of references to to big, so that `big` object get destroyed when `use==0`. And add another assignment operator, say `<=` for actual copying. I tried to implement it (below). It seems to work, but 
   I have no experience and it is hard for me to foresee, what can go wrong.
   Shouldn't be there a simpler solution?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

// print and execute cmd
#define Do(cmd) cout << "\n\n\t"<< ++line << ".\t" << #cmd << ";\n" << endl; cmd;

// print small object: name(small.id[big.id,u=big.use,x=big.x])
#define Show(avar) cout << #avar << "(" << (avar).id << "[" << ((avar).data==NULL?0:(avar).data->id) << ",u=" << ((avar).data==NULL?0:(avar).data->use) << ",x=" << ((avar).data==NULL?0:(avar).data->x) << "])" 

using namespace std;

class big{
public:
  static int N;   // biggest id in use
  int id;         // unique id for each object
  int use;        // nuber of references to this object
  int x;          // data
  big() __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;
    use=1;
    x=0;
    cout << "big.constructor.def: [" << id << ",u=" << use << ",x="<<x<<"]" << endl;
  }
  big(const int& y) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;
    x=y;
    use=1;
    cout << "big.constructor.int: [" << id << ",u=" << use << ",x="<<x<<"]" << endl;
  }
  big(const big& b) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;
    use=1;
    x=b.x;
    cout << "big.constructor.copy: [" << id << ",u=" << use << ",x="<<x<<"]" << endl;
  }
  ~big() __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    if(use>0) throw 99; // destroing referenced data!
    cout << "big.destructor: [" << id << ",u=" << use << ",x="<<x<<"]" << endl;
  }
  friend class small;
};

class small{
public:
  static int N;      // biggest id in use
  int id;            // unique id
  big * data;        // reference to the actual data
  small() __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;        
    data=NULL;       // contains no data
    cout << "small.constructor.def: ";
    Show(*this)<< endl;
  }
  small(const int& y) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;
    data=new big (y);  // relies on the big constructor
    cout << "small.constructor.int: ";
    Show(*this)<<endl;
  }
  small(const small& y) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    id=++N;
    data=y.data;      // new object refers to the same data!!
    if(data!=NULL) 
      ++(data->use);  // new reference added;
    cout << "small.constructor.copy: "; 
    Show(y) << "-->";
    Show(*this) << endl;
  }
  ~small(){
    cout << "small.destructor: ";
    Show(*this)<< endl;
    if(data!=NULL){       // is there data?
      --(data->use);      // one reference is destroyed
      if(data->use == 0)  // no references left, kill the data
    delete data;
    }
  }
  const small& operator= (const small& b) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    cout << "equal: ";
    Show(*this) << " = ";
    Show(b)<<endl;
    if(data != NULL){     // is there data in the target?
      --(data->use);      // one reference is destroyed
      if(data->use == 0)  // no references left, 
    delete data;      // kill the data
    }
    data=b.data;          // target referenses the same data as the source!
    if(data!=NULL) 
      ++(data->use);      // new references added
    cout << "Done equal: "<<endl;    
    return *this;
  }
  // <= will be used for actual copying the data
  const small& operator<= (const small& b) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    cout << "Copy: ";
    Show(*this) << " <= ";
    Show(b)<<endl;
    if(data != NULL){     // is there data in the target?
      --(data->use);      // one reference is destroyed
      if(data->use == 0)  // no references left, 
    delete data;      // kill the data
    }
    if(b.data==NULL)     // source has no data
      data=NULL;
    else
      data = new big(*(b.data)); // make new copy of the data 
                                 // via big's copy constructor
    cout << "Done copy: "<<endl;    
    return *this;
  }
  small operator+ (const small& b) __attribute__((noinline))
  {
    cout << "Plus: "; 
    Show(*this) << " + ";
    Show(b)<< endl;
    if(this->data == NULL | b.data == NULL) throw 99; // missing data for +
    small ret(data->x);
    ret.data->x += b.data->x;
    cout << "Return: "; Show(ret)<<endl;
    return ret;
  }
};


int big::N=0;
int small::N=0;

main(){
  int line=0;

  Do(small X(5); small Y(6); small Z(7); small W(X));
  Show(X) << endl;
  Show(Y) << endl;
  Show(Z) << endl;
  Show(W) << endl;

  Do(X=Y; Z<=Y);
  Show(X)<<endl;  
  Show(Y)<<endl;  // X and Y refer to the same data
  Show(Z)<<endl;  // Z has a copy of data in Y

  Do(X=Z; Y=Z);
  Show(X)<<endl;
  Show(Y)<<endl;
  Show(Z)<<endl;  // data previosly in X,Y destroyed

  Do(small* U=new small (17); small* T=new small (*U));
  Show(*U) << endl;
  Show(*T) << endl; // U and T refer to the same big

  Do(delete U);
  Show(*T) << endl; // big stays since there is another reference to it

  Do(delete T);     // big destroyed

  Do(X=(Y+Z)+W);
  Show(X)<<endl;
  Show(Y)<<endl;
  Show(Z)<<endl;  // no extra copying of data occures

  cout << "\n\tEND\n" << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1.  small X(5); small Y(6); small Z(7); small W(X);

big.constructor.int: [1,u=1,x=5]
small.constructor.int: *this(1[1,u=1,x=5])
big.constructor.int: [2,u=1,x=6]
small.constructor.int: *this(2[2,u=1,x=6])
big.constructor.int: [3,u=1,x=7]
small.constructor.int: *this(3[3,u=1,x=7])
small.constructor.copy: y(1[1,u=2,x=5])-->*this(4[1,u=2,x=5])
X(1[1,u=2,x=5])
Y(2[2,u=1,x=6])
Z(3[3,u=1,x=7])
W(4[1,u=2,x=5])


    2.  X=Y; Z<=Y;

equal: *this(1[1,u=2,x=5]) = b(2[2,u=1,x=6])
Done equal: 
Copy: *this(3[3,u=1,x=7]) <= b(2[2,u=2,x=6])
big.destructor: [3,u=0,x=7]
big.constructor.copy: [4,u=1,x=6]
Done copy: 
X(1[2,u=2,x=6])
Y(2[2,u=2,x=6])
Z(3[4,u=1,x=6])


    3.  X=Z; Y=Z;

equal: *this(1[2,u=2,x=6]) = b(3[4,u=1,x=6])
Done equal: 
equal: *this(2[2,u=1,x=6]) = b(3[4,u=2,x=6])
big.destructor: [2,u=0,x=6]
Done equal: 
X(1[4,u=3,x=6])
Y(2[4,u=3,x=6])
Z(3[4,u=3,x=6])


    4.  small* U=new small (17); small* T=new small (*U);

big.constructor.int: [5,u=1,x=17]
small.constructor.int: *this(5[5,u=1,x=17])
small.constructor.copy: y(5[5,u=2,x=17])-->*this(6[5,u=2,x=17])
*U(5[5,u=2,x=17])
*T(6[5,u=2,x=17])


    5.  delete U;

small.destructor: *this(5[5,u=2,x=17])
*T(6[5,u=1,x=17])


    6.  delete T;

small.destructor: *this(6[5,u=1,x=17])
big.destructor: [5,u=0,x=17]


    7.  X=(Y+Z)+W;

Plus: *this(2[4,u=3,x=6]) + b(3[4,u=3,x=6])
big.constructor.int: [6,u=1,x=6]
small.constructor.int: *this(7[6,u=1,x=6])
Return: ret(7[6,u=1,x=12])
Plus: *this(7[6,u=1,x=12]) + b(4[1,u=1,x=5])
big.constructor.int: [7,u=1,x=12]
small.constructor.int: *this(8[7,u=1,x=12])
Return: ret(8[7,u=1,x=17])
equal: *this(1[4,u=3,x=6]) = b(8[7,u=1,x=17])
Done equal: 
small.destructor: *this(8[7,u=2,x=17])
small.destructor: *this(7[6,u=1,x=12])
big.destructor: [6,u=0,x=12]
X(1[7,u=1,x=17])
Y(2[4,u=2,x=6])
Z(3[4,u=2,x=6])

    END

small.destructor: *this(4[1,u=1,x=5])
big.destructor: [1,u=0,x=5]
small.destructor: *this(3[4,u=2,x=6])
small.destructor: *this(2[4,u=1,x=6])
big.destructor: [4,u=0,x=6]
small.destructor: *this(1[7,u=1,x=17])
big.destructor: [7,u=0,x=17]
```

Comment: Are you positive the optimizer doesn't build the answer directly in `X`? Return value optimization?

Comment: Thank you all who bothered, especially @juanchopanza, this Don Quixote wishes to have such one. g++ -O2 does the job,if function returns the same local with all return statements. "Move semantics" would probably do the job too, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, it is called [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). Of particular relevance to this case are  [return value optimization (RVO) named and return value optimization (NRVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). It means the compiler is allowed to elide copies when returning values in certain situations. Implementing a naive addition operator is likely to result in RVO.

Note that this is an optimization that the compiler is *allowed* to do, but it isn't guaranteed to take place. But C++ has move semantics, which provide a formal means by which the underlying data of one (usually temporary) object can be "moved" to another object, without incurring in unnecessary copies. There's an article on move semantics [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: Note that in his particular code he needs NRVO not just RVO. Many compilers implement RVO in debug and release but NRVO only in release. This is a contributing factor to poor debug performance. Also, to clarify, RVO/NRVO are faster than 'moving' via move semantics

Comment: My compiler (g++ 4.5.0) did not do that, as I checked. But, thanks anyway, now I know what's (N)RVO. What is "move semantics"? Is there a way to force NRVO?

Comment: Piotr's answer effectively inlines the (normal) `operator+` and removes the return-value copy explicitly, so you can always do that.

Comment: @user1672572 there is no way to force it, but your compiler should do it if there aren't multiple return statements. GCC 4.5.0 should be OK. Move semantics is a whole topic in itself. I will try to find some useful links.

Comment: Would compiler do NRVO even if `operator =` overloaded? Could there be multiple return statements but returning the same local variable?   "I will try to find some useful links." Please/Thanks.

Comment: @user1672572 I added a move semantics link. NRVO does not depend on whether `operator=` is overloaded. Concerning the multiple return statements, it really depends on the compiler, the standard does not set any specific rules. If you find a way to avoid the multiple return statements, you are extremely likely to get NRVO.

Comment: Thank you, @juanchopanza. g++ -O2 does the job,if function returns the same local with all return statements. "Move semantics" would probably do the job too, I am not sure though. Unless compiler does something, the local will be placed in the stack and at return destroyed, so the data seem to need to be copied still. It is strange though, that such a basic thing can not be done explicitly, something like `x<-f(...)` to mean place the value directly into x.

Answer (score 1):

If the sum is a composite value an alternative approach would be to have `big::operator+` return an instance of a `sumOfBig` class which keeps pointers or references to Y and Z.

`sumOfBig` might contain member functions that computed the sum constituents on the fly, when needed.

Comment: This would be difficult, since I will need complex algebraic expressions. Besides Y an Z might change, befor value of X is requested.

Comment: to generalize this for arbitrary arithmetic expressions, you're looking for [expression templates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2526862/212858)

Comment: This is an over-simplification of a technique called `expression templates` which is used in some libraries to provide a friendly syntax without incurring the full overhead. Are you sure that there isn't already a library that does, at least in part, what you need?

Comment: No, I am not sure. But isn't it a basic need. Why the complexity?

Comment: Suppose you want to perform computations on large matrices. The complexity helps choosing specific algorithms for, say, symmetric or triangular matrices, or to only calculate an element when it is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to define and use `+=` in such case:

```
Big a, b, c;
```

Instead of:

```
a = b + c;
```

Do:

```
a=b;
a+=c;
```

Example definition of `+=`:

```
Big& Big::operator += (const Big& other)
{
   this->a += other.a;
   // ...
   return *this;
}
```

You can make your `operator +` based on `operator +=` to make them do logically the same.

Comment: It does not help: `a=b` does the copying.

Comment: that _is_ a new variable, the expression is just split across two statements (rename a=X, b=Y, c=Z and compare to your original version)

Comment: No. The whole b (however big it is) is being copied to a and the addition is then performed. My version takes two values adds then while puting the result directly to a.

Comment: Then make `big::sum(const big&,const big&);`

Answer (score 0):

First, turn on optimization and see what your compiler *actually* does: you may get (N)RVO for free as per juanchopanza's answer.

If your compiler can't do that, explicitly eliding the intermediate copy as per Piotr's answer might improve matters.

If you really need to defer evaluation of arbitrarily complex arithmetic expressions, you need expression templates (as Nicola and I mentioned in comments): if you have mutable source objects, you may need expression templates *and* copy-on-write. Neither of these are trivial. If you really need them, and really can't find a library that already does what you need ... well, I'll look out for questions about your expression template implementation, once you've researched them and made a start.